# hasOne relation on same model not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.6

I want to store a model id in same table with different column rel_id having a relation with the id column,
but the relation hasOne not working, showing this error:

> Cannot redeclare App\Models\Employee:supervisor()

```
class Employee extends Model
{   
    function supervisor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Employee','id', 'supervisor_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your model.

Comment: I think he meant show us the model where the failed function is coded -- the failure message talks to RelFunction(), not supervisor().  Most likely you have two RelFunctions in the model or a related model.  Do a search on this and let us know if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really hard to tell without a little more information and a more complete model posted, but the two most likely causes are:

1. You have two of the same methods (`RelFunction()`) on your model, or another model with the same namespace.  Do a search in your code (first your model, then globally) for RelFunction.
2. You have a namespacing problem.  You may have copied a model, or moved it to a new folder, or just incorrectly namespaced it.  Depending on what the model looks like in detail, this could inadvertently cause the error message.